# Node Js realtime server stats

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io, monitoring

I am learning more and more about nodejs and I currently have a simple nodejs/socket.io chat program running on an EC2 ubuntu instance proxied by nginx.  The basic chat works, but I would like to have a web interface for myself that shows a realtime view of what is happening with the nodejs server.  Here are some things that I would like to know:

1. How long has the nodejs server been running?
2. How many current socket.io connections are in use along with all the socket.ids?
3. How many rooms are currently open along with the room id and all the socket.ids that are currently in the room.

I know how to get all the sockets and rooms inside nodejs by using

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms  //rooms
```

and using the

```
io.sockets //sockets
```

to get all the currently open sockets.

But I don't know how to get "how long has the node.js server been running"?  My two questions are as follows:

1. How can I determine how long node.js has been running and deliverd that info to a webinterface?
2. Is my way of finding current socket/room information the best method?  It seems weird that I have to do it inside of node.js itself and there is not a netstat type tool that monitors nodejs from the outside.

I am using ubunut 14.04 on EC2 with nginx and nodejs/express/socket.io

**** Edit

I am also using pm2 to run nodejs as a service.

Comment: Also, it seems like I should be logging this kind of stuff somewhere.  So I could look back at previous days/weeks/months and see when socket /room usage spiked.  How do people do this now so they can see a history of usage?

Comment: You could use JS's Date() to determine how long node.js has been running (You save the value on start, and then do "DateNow-DateAtStart" to obtain the running time).

Comment: For a detailed log, you should select a time period, and save the actual use (Or the max values on those periods). For that, you can use setTimeout or setInterval, and use a "maxUsedRooms" variable which is reset each time you save it.

Comment: @Desaroll so you are saying that nodejs and socket.io can't log any of this stuff itself and I just have to log it myself?  sounds like it would eat up a lot of resources just to keep a decent log ... what do you think would be a reasonalbe interval?

Comment: use `process.uptime()` to find node server uptime

Comment: I didn't know about hassansin 's answer (Some time since I used Node.js), but, last time I used Socket.io, it didn't log anything about usage levels.

Comment: The "reasonable interval" depends of what do you want to obtain looking at that logs. The lower the interval, more resources used, but more details as result. It's up to you to balance that, as only YOU know the resources available, and how much detail do you need. I would suggest hourly if you want to look the logged data on a daily/weekly basis, but, as I said, you have to balance that.